# Google protocol buffers compare -default values

Tags: protocol-buffers

I saw ways to compare two protobuf messages (e.g. comparing the serialised form).
But unfortunately this doesn't work if I want to consider default values,
i.e. one protobuf message has a value explicitly set (to the default value), where the other message has this value not set (but as there is a default value this one is used).

As the default value is not serialized (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/Default_Values) I cannot compare the serialized versions....

Any ideas for an simple, generic solution?
Thanks!
Joerg

Comment: FWIW, I believe protobuf 3.0 is saying that default-valued fields will never be serialized. Though I think they are also saying that you can no longer set an explicit default value; it is always zero.

Comment: Code that uses the protocol buffer may also do different thing depending on if a field with default value is set or not, as has_<field> is false if it's not explicitly set. So you could argue that when comparing those two protobuffers they are different.